# How can I push a whole-team recurring meeting to everyone's Exchange calendar?

Tags: exchange

We have Exchange Online, which we use from the desktop Outlook app and also various mobile apps.

We do a monthly all-hands meeting, which is on our "All Hands" calendar. But people forget about it because it's not shown on their personal calendar or their mobile devices.

Is there a way to push that recurring meeting to everyone's personal Exchange calendar? Or, is there a way to force the "All Hands" calendar to be shown on all Outlook and mobile calendars?

Comment: Why don't you send a meeting invite for this meeting to all users? When they accept the meeting invite it will be put into their calendar.

Comment: It is a standing monthly meeting, so we'd prefer to just create the recurring meeting once for everyone. That way, it will always appear on every employee's calendar, and there's no risk of someone forgetting about it, or us forgetting to type in someone's name when we send the invites.

Comment: That's exactly how it works. You create the meeting once, you add all attendees to the meeting, you send a meeting invite, each attendee accepts the meeting invite and the meeting is then added to their calendar. Done. Have you not created recurring meetings for more than one attendee before? You only create the meeting one time as a recurring meeting. Then you add all attendees and send a single meeting invite, which goes out to all attendees. When each attendee accepts the meeting invite, the recurring meeting is added to their calendar.

Comment: That would work, except that we would have to remember to add each new employee to the meeting when they are hired. I'm looking for a way to make the meeting automatically appear on every employee's calendar.

Comment: If it helps, we have an "All Staff" security group that we use for permissions and for sending company-wide announcements. Could we deploy the meeting to that group somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with joe, the easiest way to solve your problem is to invite all the members as attendees when you create the meeting. And they can view the meeting in their own calendar after accepting it.

Comment: It is a standing monthly meeting, so we'd prefer to just create the recurring meeting once for everyone. That way, it will always appear on every employee's calendar, and there's no risk of someone forgetting about it, or us forgetting to type in someone's name when we send the invites.

Comment: I have tried in my environment, 
Create a security group, then create a meeting for the SG, members in the SG will receive messages about the meeting. Add new members to the SG, they can’t receive the meeting message and see the meeting in their calendar.
The only way to update the meeting to new members is to edit the meeting and send updates to attendees just added or removed

Comment: Thanks, Joyce. That's what I'm seeing too. That's disappointing, but at least I know.